# std::sort doesnt work using compare function

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
void ComputerPlayer::MakeMove(Board& b)
{
    int i,j;
    BoardCmp BC;
    std::vector<Board> tmp=successors(b);
    for (i=0;i<(int)tmp.size();i++){
      tmp.at(i).SetGrade(Evaluate(1,0,tmp.at(i)));
    }
    std::sort(tmp.begin(),tmp.end(),BC);
}
```

The vector tmp has all the right values but it isn't sorted

My whole problem is the STL sort func.

This is the header file:

```
   class Board {
public:

    Board();
    Board(const Board& b);
    Board operator= (const Board& rhs) {
        return Board(rhs);
    }
    void SetGrade(int grade){_grade=grade;}
    int GetGrade() const {return _grade;}
    friend class BoardCmp;

private:
    Piece* _board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    Point _lastP;
    Move _lastM;
    t_player_num _turn; 
    int _grade;
};

class BoardCmp
{ 
public: 
    bool operator()(Board& a,Board& b) 
    {return (a.GetGrade()<b.GetGrade()) }; 
};
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Ahh, the old `if (condition) return true; else return false;`. This is an antipattern. You should write it like this: `switch (condition) { case true: return condition ? true : false; break; case false: return not true; break; default: std::terminate(); }`

Comment: Your code won’t compile – `BC` is declared in a different scope than it’s used. Please post the **real** code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That was my first impression, too, but it's just very bad indenting on his part.

Comment: "Whats wrong?": You tell us. The compiler probably gives you an error message? Or does it compile and produce unexpected results? What exactly doesn't work? The information what exactly doesn't work as expected would be very useful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Another anti-pattern is using `tmp.at(i)`, rather than `tmp[i]`.  (Of course, in this particular context, he should be using iterators anyway.  Or a ranged `for`, if he has C++11.)

Comment: add enough code to make it a [complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `Evaluate` call is suspicious

Comment: @JamesKanze using it everywhere is safer than using it nowhere!

Comment: Also: declaring variables without initializing them (including one that isn't ever used).  (Of course, his entire `for` is just a call to `std::transform`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Using `at` everywhere is very bad practice.  I don't think I've ever used it; the cases where it is appropriate are very, very few.

Comment: let's also throw in that `b` could be passed by const reference, and the functor should have `operator()` be const and take args by const ref

Comment: @JamesKanze I think the cases it's appropriate are "newbie programmer reduces the amount of time spent on debugging Heisenbugs caused by out-of-range accesses"

Comment: Ive edited my code. just before i get to the sort call, all the values in the vector are correct. its just the sort func. comparing the _grade cells

Comment: @MattMcNabb In case of out-of-range accesses, you don't want an exception, you want a crash (assertion failure or some such).  Which is what `[]` gives you with any reasonable implementation.

Comment: The loop works just fine! its just the std::sort which doenst do anything.

Comment: @JamesKanze Stroustrup demonstrates the "at" method; even uses it to replace the [] operator in the early pages of The C+= Programming Language book (4th edition). You certainly don't get a pleasant failure when accessing vector elements out of range!

Comment: @JamesKanze relying on implementations being "reasonable" ... stopped doing that 15 years ago :)

Comment: @Poldie You don't want a "pleasant failure"; you want a radical one.  (And I'm rather surprised about Stroustrup here.  In the distant past, I know he favored `at`, but in the distant past, we hadn't realized that this was an abuse of exceptions, and that a crash was to be preferred.)

Comment: @MattMcNabb The implementation of MSC is reasonable in this respect, and it's the one most people will be using.  g++ behaves correctly too, if you pass it the correct arguments.  I imagine that covers 99% of what newbies are using.

Comment: @JamesKanze Sure.  By pleasant I meant "obvious and handled" as opposed to the UB you currently get.  Stroustrup wrote "Consequently, I often use a simple range-checking adaptation of vector" on page 97: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=Consequently,+I+often+use+a+simple+range-checking+adaptation+of+vector+:&source=bl&ots=DqrnJma_bI&sig=K0Crf05qs7L8PoawTG_xgjEIKh0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5KiqU6PmGYHB7AbW7oCIDw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Consequently%2C%20I%20often%20use%20a%20simple%20range-checking%20adaptation%20of%20vector%20%3A&f=false

Comment: @Poldie In this case, the undefined behavior has been defined by the most frequently used implementations, to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your copy assignment operator (`operator=`) is implemented incorrectly, and this will likely cause `sort` to give the wrong results.

The copy assignment operator should change the value of the object it's invoked on, while your implementation only returns a different object without changing the current one.